# How to fill an array with indexed values corresponding to a generic form of inputs with matrix structure?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I try to acquire the data entered by a user in a generic form with matrix structure. The view is as follows:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI1fh.png)

The resulting array of that view in position 0 must have (0, 0): u'winf 'and in position 5 (1, 0): u'winf'. But I can not make it look that way.I leave the code of the function and the html template

in views.py

```
def mtz_inter_chara(request):
characteristic_list = list(Characteristic.objects.all())
characteristic_len = Characteristic.objects.count()
matrix = []
for key, j in enumerate(characteristic_list):
    matrix.append((characteristic_list[key], [(j.id, i.id) for i in characteristic_list]))
print(matrix)
if request.method == 'POST':
    matrix_value = dict(((i, j), request.POST["{}-{}".format(i, j)]) for _, r in matrix for i, j in r)
    print(matrix_value)
```

html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}matriz_interdep{% endblock %} {% block content1 %}
<h1 id="h1enc">Introducir los valores</h1>{% endblock %} {% block content %}

<div id="dives">
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <table id="tabes">
            <br>
            <caption id="h1enc">
                <h2>Matriz de interdependencia</h2>
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Características</th>
                {% for dato in chara %}
                <td>{{ dato.name}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% for object, row in matrix %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{object.name}}</td>
                {% for i,j in row%}
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="winf" name="{{i}}-{{j}}" size="10">
                </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <!-- {{ form.as_table }} -->
            <br>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="table-chara" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It is not really clear to me what is not working. The *rendering* of the table?

Comment: the values ​​and positions of the array do not match with the table. For example, the first value of my array (matrix_value) is (4, 8): u'winf 'and it should be (0, 0): u'winf'

Comment: But a dictionary is *unordered*. So they can be *printed* in any order possible.

Comment: look at the image that you attach so you can see why I need the array to save the values ​​with their positions according to the view matrix

Comment: I did, I'm only saying that your `print(..)` statement will print a dictionary, and since dictionaries themselves are *unordered* regardless how you construct that dictionary, it will be *printed* in a random order.

Comment: I understand you now, then in what way should I do it to work as I want?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the people who devoted time to my question, what happens is that the tuple asosiada to each value entered is made up of the id of the objects and these id do not follow the sequence 0,1,2,3 ... As I thought, again I apologize for the time